# Can I use Netlify to host my React web app and Heroku for my node.js backend?

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I have made a website that uses React for the frontend and a nodeJS backend with MongoDB. Can I host it via Netlify + Heroku? Or is it necessary to host both on Heroku? What are the pros and cons of each? How do I make the frontend communicate with the backend? 
I have my `Procfile` with `web: node server/index.js` and I can deploy my backend through Heroku.

Comment: I'm in the same boat though I'm using mLab for my MongoDB. From what I've gathered so far, it is possible through the use of Netlify's functions feature. I'm waiting til Monday to hear back from the support staff. so if I get an answer that'll help you, I'll come back and offer what I can.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can surely host react on netlify and backend on heroku. But it may cause a problem. heroku free version uses *.heroku.com domain and frontend on .com domain . so our browser may block some kind of requests like setting cookies directly from backend . so you may get problem related to *heroku.com domain